# gtk+-2.0, glade

Tags: c, gtk

I am new in the filed of gtk+ programming. I have glade-2.6 installed on my linux system. When i try to build my gui it gives 2 options- C and LibGlade. However for libglade it says that it is deprecated and that i should use intltool instead. What does it mean and why is LibGlade deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of glade is actually very old. The most recent version is 3.6. Currently, libglade is being phased out, but for a completely different reason: there is a new alternative called [GtkBuilder](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkBuilder.html) that is included directly in GTK+ (rather than being a separate library) and has more functionality. If I were you, I would use GtkBuilder rather than libglade, and either one rather than using generated C code. The XML that libglade/GtkBuilder use is more compact and understandable and easier to modify by hand if necessary.

To be honest, I'm not sure why it is saying you should use intltool instead. As a framework for internationalization, it seems to serve a completely different purpose than libglade. I haven't programmed in GTK+ long enough to know what the history is there.